# Binding a type of Brush to a Background (or setting the binding in code)

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0

I want to let the user customize the background of of my application and select either a color or an image WITH an opacity binding. I want to do this in XAML if possible.

I seem to be very close - the code below works great with either the color OR the image brush (if I comment out the other), but I cannot figure out a way on how to return the appropriate brush depending on a boolean (UseBackgroundImage).

If you look in the code below you can see I have commented out the ImageBrush - I tried putting in a VisibilityConverter bound to UseBackgroundImage but the Brush object does not use the Visibility property.

I thought about writing a converter to return the appropriate brush but then I can't figure out how to apply the Opacity to just the background (it applies to the all the content).

```
<navigation:Frame>
    <navigation:Frame.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Config.BackgroundColorInfo.Value}" Opacity="{Binding Config.BackgroundOpacity}" />
        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="/TourneyManager;component/image.JPG" Stretch="UniformToFill" Opacity="{Binding Config.BackgroundOpacity}"/>-->
    </navigation:Frame.Background>
    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
```

I then tried setting the bindings in the code behind like this:

```
  SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
Binding b = new Binding("Config.BackgroundColorInfo.Value");
ContentFrame.SetBinding(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, b);

Binding b1 = new Binding(".BackgroundOpacity");
ContentFrame.SetBinding(SolidColorBrush.OpacityProperty, b1);

ContentFrame.Background = backgroundBrush;
```

But the SolidColorBrush class does not have the SetBinding method, so no joy there.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set a binding on a `DependencyObject` that doesn't derive from `FrameworkElement` you need to use the `BindingOperations.SetBinding` static method:-

```
SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
Binding b = new Binding("Config.BackgroundColorInfo.Value");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(backgroundBrush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, b);
```

Note the documentation indicates the you would get an exception if the target is not of type `FrameworkElement` but the documentation is out of step with the capabilities of Silverlight 4.

**Edit**

Having said that since you already have a class that your exposing as a `Config` property why not have this class simply expose a "BackgoundBrush" property of type `Brush`?

Comment: Genius, thanks Anthony - I can now set the binding of the Opacity in code and will attempt to use a converter to return the brush type if possible.

Comment: I was just about to say - despite being able to bind the opacity in the code behind I would still be left with the problem of how to reference it as the Converter would be used in the inline properties of navigation:Frame and not as navigation:Frame.Background - I think your suggestion of returning the brush type might be the easiest!

Comment: Just to end off this post with the final solution:

I return the brush in my class which determines if it is an ImageBrush or SolidColorBrush (or other) and sets the binding of the color/image/opactiy in the code.

This works great - thanks again Anthony.